# Highcharts Drawing a line with chart.renderer.path

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm looking at this formula:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands
```

And here is how I draw it:

```
chart.renderer.path(['M', someNumber, 10, 'V', 1500, 0])
                .attr({
                    'stroke-width': 2,
                    stroke: 'red',
                    id: 'vert'
                })
                .add();
```

And the line is drawn but it goes through the whole graph. I want it to be small. I think that to make it smaller i need to change the '10' but whatever value I put (even 10.000) the line's length remains the same.

Comment: @MinaGabriel Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the path attribute:

```
path(['M', someNumber, 10, 'V', 1500, 0])
```

The 'M' means moveto, "someNumber", 10 are the x, y coordinates you are moving to (this does **not draw** just moves the "pen" to where you want to start the line).  The 'V' means draw a vertical line, the 1500 is the y position to stop drawing it.  I do not believe you need the 0 (the V attribute only takes one parameter).

If you want the length of the line to be smaller adjust the 1500 parameter.

Comment: how to animate this drawing ?