# How to customize the crosshair Line for Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to customize the cross Hair with start and end point for each series.Example start with 50 and end with 250 for the Y axis Position.

Thank you in Advance

Mohideen

Comment: Hm.. what? Show us some code or an example, please.

Comment: Referecne http://jsfiddle.net/dbDRG/8/                        when You mouse over the cross hair should be my Y axis Height. In this example first week maximum Height should be In 8[Y axis]

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to do that. The entire purpose of a cross hair is to extend to both or all perimeters.

Your best bet is to look into the renderer function, and draw your own line on hover instead.

Some reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver
- [Highcharts Drawing a line with chart.renderer.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454415/highcharts-drawing-a-line-with-chart-renderer-path)

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your suggestion. for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/dbDRG/10/ how to find out the Height dynamically(blue and red ) color Lines .

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? It looks like you are already doing that. What information are you looking to retrieve, and for what purpose? These functions might be of help: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels, http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toValue